# Can't play sounds inside a jarfile

Tags: java, embedded-resource, javasound

I'm having problems with playing sounds from the jar file.
this is the code I have for playing the sounds:

```
    public class Sounds {

    public static void playClickSound() {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("resources/sounds/click.wav")));
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void playBuySound() {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("resources/sounds/buy.wav")));
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

And other class that is using the Sounds.class file:

```
//other stuff..
    Sounds.playBuySound();
//another stuff..
```

But this code doesn't even play it in editor..
I need to make the sounds work even if I export it to a jar file.

Is there any simple solution?

Comment: Use URL's, not Files, when addressing within a jar. Also, you should only load the sound file once, instead of reloading it with each play. Clips will not play until the entire sound file has been loaded into memory. If you want to refer to the file every time, SourceDataLine is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply play a file like you were trying to do, you need to use the getResource method of the class that you are using.  For example, try this code

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sounds.class.getResource("/resources/sounds/click.wav"));
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();
```

Comment: I suspect that the argument to getResource should not contain "resources" and should start with a slash.

Comment: Thanks! I had it working before, but totally forgot it :D.
There are so many ways to make it work and to make it not work :D

Comment: Now that you successfully helped me, my game is now fully playable.
You can now play it if you're interrested.
Here's a very short an laggy showcase of the game + download in the desc. :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5SXRrJk9lo

I'm still a beginner in Java, but I wrote this game within a week.
Now the game has 1290 lnes of code in total. Main.class - 1059 lines, Save.class - 42 lines, Sounds.class - 34 lines, VersionError.class - 75 lines.